# SQL Server UNION SUM misses repeated values

Tags: sql, sum, union

I have 3 independent querys that I would like to sum the values obtained in each query. These querys obtain a count value for each day of a month:

query one

```
day|val| 
1  | 2 
2  | 6 
3  | 5* 
4  | 2 
5  | 7
```

query 2

```
day|val|
2  | 1
3  | 5*
10 | 5
11 | 2
12 | 7
```

I am using the instruction:

```
select day, SUM(val) 
from query1 UNION query2
group by day
```

I found out that when a value is repeated instead of sum it would use one of the repeated values, for axample the days number 3 both have value 5. the instruction would give onlye value 5 instead of 10.

This is supposed to give me a report of total of values per day in a month but the report is wrong because of this problem caused by UNION
How can i fix it?

Comment: Check difference between `UNION` (which removes duplicates) and `UNION ALL` (which not remove duplicates)

Comment: Thanks. I didn´t know thera was a UNION ALL

Comment: It seems like it is actually a duplicate question, maybe I Just dind't know how to find the answer. Now what should I do?

Comment: Marcos, if you feel that the question is sufficiently addressed there is no need to do anything! Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) for a little more information on what StackOverflow considers to be a duplicate, and why we mark it the way we do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`union` removes duplicates, as you noticed. Instead, you should use `union all`:

```
SELECT   day, SUM(val) 
FROM     query1 UNION ALL query2
GOURP BY day
```

Comment: Thanks man, that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
select day, sum(val) 
from (
select day,val from table1
union all
select day,val from table2) t
group by day;
```

`union all` preserves duplicates.

Comment: Thanks man, that fixed it